# Is there a way in Vue 2 to have a component that just applies a class to the sub components and then disappears?

Tags: vue.js

Imagine this tree of components:

```html
<stack>
 <some-component />
 <div></div>
 <other-component />
</stack>
```

Now the `stack` component should only apply classes to children, but not be rendered in the DOM (e.g. `margin-top` class `mt-32`. and `mt-12`)

The resulting DOM could look like this:

```html
<div class="some-componen mt-32">...</div>
<div class="mt-12">...</div>
<div class="other-component mt-12">...</div>
```

Opposing to this:

```html
<div class="stack">
  <div class="some-component">...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="other-component">...</div>
</div>
```

The reason behind this is to have an easier time coding, and avoid unnecessary nesting of the DOM tree and keep it more readable as well.

Comment: How is `stack` supposed to be aware of which classes to apply, and where? This could be the case for slots and fragment, or not.

Comment: This is basically the question asked in a different way. Is there a way to modify children and apply classes to them. In this case: Add class `mt-32` to the first child. Add `mt-12` to every other child.

Comment: There is. Just querySelector in mounted and add a class. It's jQuery way of thinking that is generally discouraged in proper Vue code.

Comment: That always works but as you said, that is not a suggested way. I am searching for a "vue way".

Comment: See the comment regarding slots and fragment.

Comment: I know slots and fragments, but I don't know how you could implement it. Also given constraint that the amount of children is dynamic.

Comment: I can't provide an example in Vue 2 as it's more hacky and time-consuming than in Vue 3. Basically you need to provide `some` and `other` slots, modify their nodes inside render function by adding classes to their nodes (`node.data.staticClass`), see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Complete-Example for similar example, also return Fragment comp from render function to get rid of div wrapper. Either that, or flaky jQuery-like code that modifies DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following for stack.vue:

```js
<template>
    <slot />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        updateDOMCls() {
            document.querySelectorAll('.Stack__firstEl').forEach(function(el) {
                el.classList.add('mt-32');
            })
            document.querySelectorAll('.Stack__otherEl').forEach(function(el) {
                el.classList.add('mt-12');
            })

        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.updateDOMCls();
    }
}
</script>
```

And leverage slot to provide dynamic components. PLEASE ENSURE TO GIVE CLASSES **Stack_firstEl** and **Stack_otherEl**:

```html
    <stack>
      <div class="Stack__firstEl"></div>
      <div class="Stack__otherEl"></div>
      <div class="Stack__otherEl"></div>
      <div class="Stack__otherEl"></div>
    </stack>
```

Comment: I seem to have not been clear enough: I want the `stack` component to apply these classes to it's children. It should be a reusable component with dynamic children. I don't want to type `mt-*` but rather the `stack`component should apply these classes to the children.

Comment: @oemera Then make a component which does just that.

Comment: That is the question. How do I make a component that applies classes to sub components, but never appears on the the DOM. In this case the component would apply `mt-32` to the first child and `mt-12` to every other child. To be clear: The idea is, that I will **never** have to write `mt-*`, but the component does this automatically.

Comment: That would be the stack component: <script></script><template><comp1 class="asdf"><comp2 class="dflguh"></template>

Comment: The children should be dynamic. In your example you explicitly used `comp1` and `comp2` but this should also work for any other component.

Comment: Maybe you can do it with slot, but I don't thinks it's possible what you want. Maybe I don't understand what exactly you want.

Comment: I don't think it's possible and if it was possible it is probably anti pattern..

Comment: @oemera, I have updated the code. Kindly chekc if it suits your requiremnt now.
You may choose to make mt-32 and mt-12 dynamic by passing them as props to stack component